# two ways to compute an integral

Tags: calculus

One way to compute $\int \frac{dx}{a-x}$ for $a>0$ is $- \int \frac{d(a-x)}{a-x} = - \ln |a-x|$; another way is factoring out the $a$ in the denominator first:
$$
\int \frac{\frac{1}{a}}{1 - \frac{x}{a}} dx = - \int \frac{d \Big(1 - \frac{x}{a}\big)}{1 - \frac{x}{a}} = - \ln |1 - \frac{x}{a}|.
$$
While it is understandable that two anti-derivatives can differ by a constant, which, in this case, is $\ln(a)$, how to understand that an equivalent algebraic operation leads to two different results? Where did I go wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: You didn't go wrong anywhere... I think the jist is that we can manipulate some expressions in many (legal) ways, and our result of an integral will just different by a constant.

Comment: [Does this help?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/865943/solving-indefinite-integrals-gives-multiple-answers-are-all-those-answers-corre)

Comment: $$- \ln |a-x| = - \ln |a|\left |1-\frac{x}{a}\right| = - \ln |a| - \ln \left |1-\frac{x}{a}\right|$$

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3453558/getting-different-answers-when-integrating-using-different-techniques